# wpf3d rectangle hit test

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have an application with 3D objects that reside in Viewport3D and I want the user to be able to select them by dragging a rectangle on the screen.

I tried applying GeometryHitTestParameters (with rectangle geometry) on the Viewport3D in order to get the results, but I get an exception telling me that it is unsuppoted with Viewport3D. Only PointHitTestParameters are supported.

Does anybody know any elegant way to do it, except calculating it myself (for example - projecting all 3D objects to 2D and doing manual geometry intersections with a rectangle)?

Comment: Have you tried the approach from this link? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf3d/archive/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing.aspx

Comment: Of course. This is the known approach for point/ray hit-testing. I am looking for rectangle hit-testing. It's not an integrated part of the framework, but maybe somebody knows how I can use the framework to elegantly achieve my task.

Anyway, GeometryHitTestParameters doesn't work on Viewport3D. Therefore I cannot use it for my rectangle hit-testing.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is better way than iterating through selected rectangle points:

```
    private void view_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        const double offset = 3.0; // I will test in a square 7x7
        var mouse = e.GetPosition(this);
        var items = new HashSet<Model3D>();
        for (double x = mouse.X - offset; x <= mouse.X + offset; x++)
            for (double y = mouse.Y - offset; y <= mouse.Y + offset; y++) {
                PointHitTestParameters pointparams = new PointHitTestParameters(new Point(x, y));
                Model3D result = null;
                VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(view, null, rawresult => {
                    var rayResult = rawresult as RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult;
                    if (rayResult != null)
                        items.Add(rayResult.ModelHit);
                    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
                }, pointparams);
            }
        // temporary ListBox to show items
        list.ItemsSource = items.Select(item => item as GeometryModel3D == null ? null : (item as GeometryModel3D).Material as object);
    }
```

See [MSDN How to: Hit Test in a Viewport3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745195.aspx)

Comment: Of course there is. For example, manually calculating the viewing frustum using camera parameters, and then manually traversing the visual tree and performing model-against-frustum containment test. High speed can be achieved using bounding boxes.

But this is reinventing the wheel. They are already doing it with ray-based hit testing inside WPF. The only difference is that the intersection test is ray-model and not frustum-model.

I wasn't able to find a working code for this scenario on the web and I thought somebody here knows where I can find efficient code that does the job.